# What's the difference between nextDouble and nextFloat in the random class?

Tags: java, random

To my knowledge, they both do the same thing, which is generate a value between 0.0 and 1.0, right?

Comment: yes, -- except one returns a double, and one returns a float...

Comment: `double`is to `float` as `long` is to `int`. Not really sure what the question is here - you seem to have answered it yourself.

Comment: P.S. presumably you think `nextBoolean` is the same too?

Answer (score 1):

One return a float, one return a double.

Just try this:

```
    Random random = new Random();
    System.out.println("nextFloat: " + random.nextFloat() + ", nextDouble: " + random.nextDouble());
```

that returns:
    nextFloat: 0.9613963, nextDouble: 0.9364254125546306